# Prevent (Of …) auto completion in the Visual Basic editor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

**Repro**:

1. Start VS 2015
2. Create a new VB.NET console application
3. Start typing inside Sub Main():

   ```
   Dim s = {"a", "b"}
   s.Se
   ```
4. Observe that Visual Studio helpfully offers the `Select` extension method:

[image: screenshot]

5. Hit `(` to auto-complete and start providing parameters to the method.

**Actual result**: `s.Select(Of …)()`

**Desired result**: `s.Select()`

I don't want the `(Of …)` part since type inference works perfectly fine without it in 99% of the cases and it clutters my code. Is there a way to tell auto-complete not to do that?

**Note**: Apparently, this "issue" only affects the `Enumerable.Select(Of T)` and `Enumerable.SelectMany(Of T)` extension methods. `Enumerable.Cast(Of T)` and a custom `Select(Of T)` extension method work fine (no `(Of …)`).

Comment: If you press `TAB` instead of `(` VS auto-completes to `s.Select`. Then type `(` and start with the parameters.

Comment: I would hate to type in that way, especially given that all VS before 2015 do not add the `Of`.

Comment: Judging by the fact that the caret goes after `Select(Of ...)(`, instead of staying in between the first parentheses after `Of`, I believe it's a bug where it inserts `Text` of the autocomplete list element into the editor instead of `Value`. It does make entering code annoying to the degree of ragequitting.

Comment: @GSerg: I agree, it looks like a bug. I have created an MS connect entry: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3118772

Comment: For me, of all generic methods from the autocomplete list, only `Cast` and `OfType` work properly, all others give the `Of`. Incidentally, these two are the only ones that display a proper help tooltip to the right of the list, the others display an empty tooltip (can also be seen on your screenshot, the little bump on the top right of the list).

Comment: And if I define my own `IEnumerable` extensions they also do not give the `Of` and show a tooltip.

Answer (score -1):

The intellisense in Visual studio select the auto complete features based on the data type.

The declaration below declares s as an object.

```
Dim s = {"a", "b"}
```

This is the reason the intellisense list show the functions related to object. Declare s as shown below to get the right list.

```
Dim s As string = {"a", "b"}
```

Comment: `The declaration below declares s as an object` - in old versions of VB.NET, yes. In the version discussed in the question, `s` is declared as `String()` (array of string), hence the premise of the question. If it was declared as Object, the entire question makes no sense.